# Suggested refactorings of this Ruby time-to-string method?

Tags: ruby

I have the following code that gets the difference in time between now and when an alarm is supposed to go off (i.e. "alarm goes off in 23 minutes, 56 seconds").

```
def time_to_alarm_in_words
  #AN EMPTY STRING WE WILL BE ADDING TO
  time_in_words = ''

  #THE TIME TO THE ALARM IN SECONDS
  total_seconds = (time - Time.now).to_i

  #SOME BASIC TIME UNIT VARIABLES
   days = total_seconds / 86400
   hours = (total_seconds / 3600) - (days * 24)
   minutes = (total_seconds / 60) - (hours * 60) - (days * 1440)
   seconds = total_seconds % 60

  #ONLY PROCEED IF THE TIME TO THE ALARM IS POSITIVE(I.E. IN THE FUTURE)
  unless total_seconds <= 0
    #BUILD A HASH WITH THE TIME UNTIL THE ALARM
    time_hash = {"days" => (total_seconds / 86400), 
               "hours" => ((total_seconds / 3600) - (days * 24)), 
               "minutes" => ((total_seconds / 60) - (hours * 60) - (days * 1440)),
               "seconds" => (total_seconds % 60)}

  #IF THE TIME SEGMENT IS POSITIVE, ADD IT TO THE STRING
  time_hash.each_pair do |time_segment,length|
    if value > 0

      #i.e. add "22 hours," to the empty string
      time_in_words << "#{length} #{time_segment},"
    end
  end

  #CHOP OFF THE TRAILING ','
  time_in_words.chop!

  #RETURN THE RESULT
  return time_in_words + " ago"
end
```

I have a feeling I could cut this down by half. Any suggestions?!

Comment: Use [distance_of_time_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words)(Time.now, Time.now.end_of_day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Courtesy of the clever helper method from this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136248/how-to-generate-a-human-readable-time-range-using-ruby-on-rails

```
def humanize secs
  [[60, :seconds], [60, :minutes], [24, :hours], [1000, :days]].map{ |count, name|
    if secs > 0
      secs, n = secs.divmod(count)
      "#{n.to_i} #{name}"
    end
  }.compact.reverse.join(' ')
end

def time_to_alarm_in_words time
  #AN EMPTY STRING WE WILL BE ADDING TO
  time_in_words = ''

  #THE TIME TO THE ALARM IN SECONDS
  total_seconds = (time - Time.now).to_i

  time_in_words = humanize total_seconds

  #RETURN THE RESULT
  return time_in_words + " in the future"
end
```